# How to filter OrderNbr on SOOrder Screen by current user login?

Tags: acumatica

As my title of question, I want to filter the orderNbr that user has already created it with Type CS.

[image]

For example:

1. User Sophak, created OrderNbr: ARI16-000001
2. User zzz, created OrderNbr: ARI16-000003
3. When user Sophak logins so the orderNbr should show only the CS that created by her. But when user admin login I want to see all orderNbr.

I think I should customize it with BQL:

```
 public class administrator : Constant<String>
 {
     public administrator(): base("Administrator")
     { }
 }

 [PXDBString(15, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = ">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC")]
 [PXDefault()]
 [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Order Nbr.", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
 [SO.RefNbr(typeof(Search2<SOOrder.orderNbr, LeftJoinSingleTable<Customer, On<SOOrder.customerID, Equal<Customer.bAccountID>, And<Where<Match<Customer, Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>>,
 LeftJoin<PX.SM.Users, On<SOOrder.createdByID, Equal<PX.SM.Users.pKID>>,
 LeftJoin<PX.SM.UsersInRoles, On<PX.SM.Users.username, Equal<PX.SM.UsersInRoles.username>,Or<PX.SM.UsersInRoles.rolename, Equal<administrator>>>>>>,
 Where<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<Optional<SOOrder.orderType>>, And<Where<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<SOOrderTypeConstants.transferOrder>,Or<Customer.bAccountID, IsNotNull>>>>,
 OrderBy<Desc<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>), Filterable = true)]
 [SO.Numbering()]
 [PX.Data.EP.PXFieldDescription]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first customize BQL-query for the SO.RefNbr attribute with CacheAttached handler inside your SOOrderEntry BLC extension to filter records in dropdown grid of the OrderNbr selector.

After that make sure to additionally customize BQL-query for the Document data view - this step is required for proper operations of navigation buttons (First, Prev, Next, Last)